# Intalion and tasks with a deadline

Tags: task, bpmn, deadlines

Unlike [Oracle's solution](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25178_01/doc.1111/e15176/timers_bpmpd.htm#CIHGEHCI), I'm not so sure but I think Intalio can't handle tasks with a deadline.

What I want is the task to be canceled once 48 hours have passed and to follow a different sequence flow in this case. Just like this.

[image]

Is there any way this purpose could be done with Intalio? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intalio lets you attach an interrupter timer to a sub-process(group of task in the process flow). When that timer is hit (48 hours in your case) execution jumps out of the sub-process to the next task in line. I think this might be exactly what you are looking for.

Human interaction tasks (like completing a form) also have a deadline option that you can set in the mapper. When the deadline is hit the human interaction task is canceled and the process automatically moves on.

Edit. Added a picture to show how it looks in Intalio designer. When timer is hit process moves on to Task 3. You can also execute a separate stream (optional task in this example)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AmrN.png

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: So I'm obliged to use a subprocess?

Comment: Are you looking to do this for a human interaction task or just a task? 
For human interaction tasks you can just set a deadline.
For a normal task just select the task, right click it and choose format>group is sub-process. This creates an inline sub-process. You can then attach timers to this sub-process.